# Positioning of full tikzpicture relative to coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to `anchor` a full `tikzpicture` at a specific coordinate with `north`, `east`, `center`, ... arguments? I configured a grid showing background coordinates when being activated in the `frame` by `g` option. Then I drawed a tikzpicture on top of it (in this case at `(0,3.5)`), which is the top left corner of my beamer slide. Now I wonder how to vertically align the full tikzpicture at 0,0 with anchor `west` or at 7,0 with anchor `center`. I generally use `overlay` to be able to independently draw tikzpictures on my slides.

Code:

```
\documentclass[8pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,arrows,fit,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows.spaced,angles,quotes,decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.shapes,decorations.text,patterns,overlay-beamer-styles,external,calc,math,backgrounds,automata}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[overlay,remember picture,shift={([xshift=1cm,yshift=-0.41cm]current page.west)}]

\defbeamertemplate{background}{mydefault}{%
    %
}
\defbeamertemplate{background}{g}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \y in {3.5,3,...,-3.5}
    \draw[opacity=0.3,line width=0.1] (0,\y) -- (14,\y);
    \foreach \x in {0,0.5,...,14}
    \draw[opacity=0.3,line width=0.1] (\x,3.5) -- (\x,-3.5);
    
    \begin{scope}[opacity=0.4]
    \foreach \x in {0,1,...,14}
    \foreach \y in {3.5,3,2.5,...,-3.5}
    \node[font=\footnotesize] at (\x,\y) {\x, \y};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[mydefault]%
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{g}[true]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{background}[g]%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[g]
    \frametitle{Agenda}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[Numbox/.style={rectangle,draw=magenta,fill=magenta,text=white,font=\bfseries,text width=12pt, minimum height=28pt,anchor=north west,align=center},
        Textbox/.style={rectangle,draw=magenta,text width=7cm, minimum height=28pt,anchor=north west,align=left,font=\bfseries,inner xsep=9pt}
        ]
        
        \tikzmath{
            \numskip=9pt;
            \textnumskip=3pt;
        }   
        ]
        
        \node[Numbox] (I) at (0,3.5) {I.};
        \node[Textbox] (IT) at ([xshift=\textnumskip]I.north east) {Problemstellung und Forschungsfragen};
        
        
        \node[Numbox] (II) at ([yshift=-\numskip]I.south west) {II.};
        \node[Textbox] (IIT) at ([xshift=\textnumskip]II.north east) {Problemstellung und Forschungsfragen};
        
        
        \node[Numbox] (III) at ([yshift=-\numskip]II.south west) {III.};
        \node[Textbox] (IIIT) at ([xshift=\textnumskip]III.north east) {Problemstellung und Forschungsfragen};
        
        
        \node[Numbox] (IV) at ([yshift=-\numskip]III.south west) {IV.};
        \node[Textbox] (IVT) at ([xshift=\textnumskip]IV.north east) {Problemstellung und Forschungsfragen};
        
        \node[Numbox] (V) at ([yshift=-\numskip]IV.south west) {V.};
        \node[Textbox] (VT) at ([xshift=\textnumskip]V.north east) {Problemstellung und Forschungsfragen};
                
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, but my question is more how to define an anchor point of the tikzpicuture at a coordinate (for instance north east). Shifting origin won't change the anchor point.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411535/tikz-overlay-option-does-not-draw-nodes-referencing-local-bounding-box (accepted answer).

Comment: I do not really understand the question. Perhaps you want `\node[label={[below,xshift=-0.4cm]2,0},overlay=false] at (2,0) {+};`? Yet it would IMHO make more sense if you gave some directive of the sort that the `+` should end up at `(current page.center)`, say.